# Wait for QMutex/QSemphore/QWaitCondition and a QT signal

Tags: qt, signals, producer-consumer

I'm trying to implement a producer/consumer pattern in QT with threads. Reading the page [Thread Support in Qt](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/threads.html) and google brings me to the question: How do I wait for a QMutex/QSemphore/QWaitCondition and a signal to quit if the main applications wants to end the existence of the thread.

In other words:

- Wait for a working job -> do the work
- wait for a quit signal -> quit thread

Can I achive this with one eventloop in QT? Or isn't this the way to go for this case?